# echo -e backslash escapes not being respected in sh

Tags: bash, ubuntu, centos, echo, sh

I have a shell script that I wish to run on different Linux servers. When I run the echo command with the -e option and escape characters in the string it doesn't execute as expected on the sh shell on Ubuntu 12.04 or Ubuntu 11.04. The two servers we have in use that I would like the script to work on are running CentOS 5.3 and Ubuntu 12.04. When I run the following command in bash on the two servers the expected output is produced:

```
$ echo -e "line1\nline2"
line1
line2
```

When I run the same command in sh on the CentOS machine the correct output is also produced. But when I run the command in sh on Ubuntu 12.04 or 11.04 the following output is produced:

```
$ echo -e "line1\nline2"
-e line1
line2
```

Interesting if I run the below in sh on Ubuntu it automatically interprets the escape characters.

```
$ echo "line1\nline2"
line1
line2
```

The script needs to run in the sh shell and should be portable across different machines. Any solutions. I'd also much appreciate a link to some docs explaining why or how this stuff happens.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `sh` shell in Ubuntu is `dash`. Its built-in echo doesn't have an `-e` option (and consequently it simply echoes it, as you saw), or, rather, it doesn't have a way of turning the escape behaviour off.

Use `/bin/echo` instead.

To check what shell you're using try `echo $SHELL`

```
$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
```

Comment: @MarwanAlsabbagh `/bin/echo` isn't a good alternative. If you really want to use `/bin/sh`, use `printf`, otherwise use a different shell.

Comment: Amazing: POSIX 7 specifies that the effects of backslash escapes are undetermined: "A string to be written to standard output. If the first operand is -n, or if any of the operands contain a <backslash> character, the results are implementation-defined." I had relied on that so many times! [source](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html#tag_20_37_05)

Answer (score 0):

`echo` is hopelessly inconsistent between implementations; if you need consistent behavior for nontrivial applications (e.g. escape sequences), use `printf` instead (and remember to add a final \n explicitly):

```
$ printf "line1\nline2\n"
line1
line2
```